# How to fix error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 114 6 Table 'bbs_hnq.configs' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `configs` limit 1)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

//use App\Models\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

        \Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
        $config = Config::firstOrNew(['id' => 1]);
        view()->share('config', $config);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('settings', function () {
            return Config::all();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you show the code for your Config model and the migrate file/schema for the table it relates to.

Answer (score 0):

Here you made mistake to create table. You suppose created table name as **config**.

Change your Model **Config.php**

```
class Config extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'config'; //as per your table name
}
```

Comment: Can you show your table which linked with Config model?

Comment: Add your comment in  english.